# Gradle syncing failed in Android studio 3.2 canary 15 for creating app bundle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-app-bundle

My requirement is generating app bundle, to achive that we need to install (1)-Android 3.2 Canary 15. (2) -Android gradle plugin version should be 3.2.0+ in pproject level build.gradle So I have this:  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha15' and gradle version should be 4.5+ in gradle-wrapper.properties. Below is my Project level build.gradle file. Points to be noted in this are: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha15'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' ext.play_services_version = '14.0.0'
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    ext.support_lib_version = '26.1.0'
    ext.build_tool_version = '26.0.2'
    ext.play_services_version = '14.0.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha15'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://appboy.github.io/appboy-android-sdk/sdk" }
        maven { url  "http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
//        maven {
//            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
//            name 'Google'
//        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

This play_services_version is used in my one of the module to keep consistency for firebase and google play service. Please see that module's build.gradle  file dependencies block below, where I have used it.

```
dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_lib_version}"
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${play_services_version}"
    api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${play_services_version}"
    api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${play_services_version}"
    // Note : We have added wearable as AppBoy needs it.
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:${play_services_version}"

    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    // compile project(':thirdParty:facebook')
    // Note : We have fixed the facebook sdk version to 4.8.2 as latest facebook sdk versions
    //        result in compilation error in care application since care care application's and its sdk's
    //        compile sdk version is 22 and not 23.
    api 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'

    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${play_services_version}"
    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${play_services_version}"
    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:${play_services_version}"
    implementation project(':thirdParty:NumberPicker')
    api project(':thirdParty:MaterialDialogs')
    implementation project(':thirdParty:viewpagerindicator')
    api project(':thirdParty:CustomRatingBar')

    api 'com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:2.2.+'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.0.0'
    // Note : Don't use compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+' as stripe does not maintain backward compatibility
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${support_lib_version}"

    // compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'
    // compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0'
    // compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
    // compile project(':thirdParty:card.io')
    implementation project(':thirdParty:material-calendarview')
    //compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    // compile ('com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4') {
    //        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'
    //    }
    implementation project(':thirdParty:facncycoverflow')

    api 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.1'
    api "com.android.support:design:${support_lib_version}"
//    compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.9.+'

    api ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3')
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.getCompileConfiguration().exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
        variant.getRuntimeConfiguration().exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
//    implementation ('io.socket:engine.io-client:0.8.3')
//    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
//        variant.getCompileConfiguration().exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
//        variant.getRuntimeConfiguration().exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
//    }

    api "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0"
    api "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
    api 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-alpha1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-alpha1'

    api 'com.siftscience:sift-android:0.9.8'
    implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.16.0'

    api project(':patternLib-android:PatternLib')
    api('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    api 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:+'

    api project(':thirdParty:material-edittext')
    api project(':thirdParty:custom_edittext')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
    api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}
```

In my gradle-wrapper.properties file I am using gradle version 4.6

```
#Tue May 29 20:39:46 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Now come to the issues: gradle syncing failed every time with follwing screen shots: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-*****

[image]

Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-*****

[image]

Starts in play-services: play-services-map, play-services-analytics, play-services-location etc and starts in firebase are firebase-crash, firebase-core, firebase-invite, firebase-config. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding dependency version for maps and firebase as 15.0.0. It may work, if it doesn't check out the official documentation for the same.

For firebase check this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Thanks @Amit Jangid. I already tried adding 15.0.0 It doesn't work for me. Currently I am using ext.play_services_version = '15.0.1'  and ext.firebase_version = '16.0.0' and implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0' Finally I am able to create app bundle.  One more thing to be note is with above set up, it may give error if define minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest file, to solve this error just remove it from manifest and define in build.gradle of respective module in side android block defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 26 }